# Makefile targets with same file prefix, several file extensions

Tags: makefile

I'm writing a makefile that, as part of its operation, downloads and extracts a zipfile containing an ESRI shapefile. Shapefile is a misnomer, because a shapefile is actually a directory containing files named like shape.[shp,dbf,prj,shp.html,shp.xml,sbn,sbx]

Is there a way of defining a list of extensions to append to a common file prefix in a make target? Something like:

```
shape.[mylistofexts] : shape.zip
    unzip stuff...
```

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8969015/working-with-multiple-source-file-extensions-in-a-makefile) which appears to be the inverse, in that they have a single target with multiple sources that each require processing. My neophyte's intuition is that this should be a simpler case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature you want here is multiple patterns in a single target.

From the [Pattern Rule Examples](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Examples) section of the GNU make makefile:

> This pattern rule has two targets:
>
> ```
> %.tab.c %.tab.h: %.y
>         bison -d $<
> ```
>
> This tells make that the recipe ‘bison -d x.y’ will make both `x.tab.c` and `x.tab.h`. If the file `foo` depends on the files `parse.tab.o` and `scan.o` and the file `scan.o` depends on the file `parse.tab.h`, when `parse.y` is changed, the recipe ‘bison -d parse.y’ will be executed only once, and the prerequisites of both `parse.tab.o` and `scan.o` will be satisfied. (Presumably the file `parse.tab.o` will be recompiled from `parse.tab.c` and the file `scan.o` from `scan.c`, while `foo` is linked from `parse.tab.o`, `scan.o`, and its other prerequisites, and it will execute happily ever after.)

So you want to write:

```
%.shp, %.dbf %.prj %.shp.html %.shp.xml %.sbn %.sbx: %.zip
        @unzip ...
```

Which can be shortened (technically) to:

```
$(addprefix %.,dbf prj shp.html shp.xml sbn sbx): %.zip
        @unzip ...
```