# How to compile multiple file types in the same way using Make

Tags: c++, makefile, gnu-make

In a `Makefile` i have the following two semi-generic targets to handle compilation of any `.cc` and `.cpp` files:

```
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: %.cc
    mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCDIRS) -c $< -MD -o $@

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: %.cpp
    mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCDIRS) -c $< -MD -o $@
```

Seeing as they are very similar (only the file extension differs), could i merge them somehow to create one generic target for both file types?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Working with multiple source file extensions in a makefile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8969015/working-with-multiple-source-file-extensions-in-a-makefile)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, no, you cannot combine them.  You have two options.  The first is to use an `eval` statement as in the answer linked to by Amon Zilca.

The other is to just keep the recipe in a variable and re-use that:

```
define COMPILE
  mkdir -p $(dir $@)
  $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCDIRS) -c $< -MD -o $@
endef

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: %.cc
        $(COMPILE)

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: %.cpp
        $(COMPILE)
```

Personally I like this method better; the `eval` method just feels like overkill to me unless you have a LOT of extensions, or you want to make it easy to add more just by tweaking a variable.

Oh, note you can use `$(@D)` instead of `$(dir $@)`, as well.